# Push Notification from client

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, notifications

I am testing the push notification such that when I press a button on the app, all the others who have the same application installed gets a push notification. The one who is sending the notification won't get any.

I been looking around similar queries here but not able to get it to work. In terms of the push itself, my log shows that "Parse push is sent". But I do not get any notification on any of my physical devices nor emulator.

Note that I am using **Parse** and the setup is done correctly and able to send notifications from the Parse.com site. Only having trouble when trying to send it from a client's device.

Am I supposed to explicitly create a channel and user for this? I tried but only had options to create audience with conditions.

```
public void sendParse(View view){
    try {
        // Associate the device with a user
        ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        installation.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        installation.saveInBackground();

        ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", "Everyone");
        pushQuery.whereNotEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        pushQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        push.setQuery(pushQuery);
        push.setMessage("Testing 1 2 3...");
        push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                    Log.i("zx", "Push is sent!");
                }
            });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the method that sends the push through the client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
pushQuery.whereNotEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
```

These two lines are incompatible, you should remove the "whereEqualTo" line.

Another thing you can do is in the callback:

```
 ...
public void done(ParseException e){
            if(e!=null)
                e.printStackTrace();
...
}
```

To check if there were errors